# Access parameters through URL in index of Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

OK, what I need may sound fairly easy (or complicated? - I don't know), but here it is :

In CodeIgniter, given a controller e.g. `test` you can do :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class test extends CI_Controller {

    public function sub($param1="", $param2="")
    {

    }
}
?>
```

Which means that you can access either :

- mysite.com/test/sub
- mysite.com/test/sub/someparam1
- mysite.com/test/sub/someparam1/someparam2

However, what happens if I want to "omit" the `sub` part?

Ok, so I thought about doing the very same thing in the `index` function of the controller. Like :

```
public function index($param1="", $param2="")
{
}
```

So that I could directly access either :

- mysite.com/test
- mysite.com/test/someparam1
- mysite.com/test/someparam1/someparam2

However, given CI's inner design, when I try this, it keeps looking for a `someparam1' method in the`test` controller which obviously does not exist.

So, what how would you go about that?

---

**P.S.**

*1. Please, let's avoid solutions having to do with `.htaccess` and obscure redirections and let's stick to the most CI-friendly approach available (if there is one).*

*2. Don't suggest my creating the appropriate functions (instead of using some variable accessor) - if I wanted to do it this way, I would already have done it*

*3. The parameters should preferably be part of a SEO-friendly URL, and not take them with `$_GET`, etc. (e.g. mysite.com/test/?param1=someparam1&param2=someparam2)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in config/routes.php

```
$route['test/(:any)'] = 'test/index/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have  to access your site like this:

- mysite.com/test/index
- mysite.com/test/index/someparam1
- mysite.com/test/index/someparam1/someparam2

Or you can rewrite in routes.php file

```
$route['test/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'test/index/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Well, what about eliminating that `index` part as well? (If the `index` is there, then I wouldn't care if it was something else, too. Point is to have nothing between the controller name and the potential params...)

Comment: then you can do it using my other method in rewrite with routes.php file.

Comment: Just tried your additional edit, and - though it definitely looks close - it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

**You could use some routing configuration:**

```
//if arguments start by a number
$route['test/(^[0-9].+)'] = 'test/index/$1';

//if argument start by a set of choice
$route['test/(str1|str2|str3)(:any)'] = 'test/index/$1$2';
//this can prevent from name collision between methods and first argument
```

**Or, in your controller use magic method:**

if any method in that controller not match the URI, this method will be called.

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'index'), $args );
}
```